# How to print 1 when any bit of a number equals 0?

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

I need to print out the value 1 when any bit of a number equals 0, and am currently struggling with how I would go about doing this. I am not supposed to use any equality or inequality tests, and am basically restricted to just bit-level and logic operations. Any ideas?

```
int b = 15;
printf("prints 1 when any bit of a number equals 0: %d\n", //PRINT GOES HERE);

b = 10;
printf("prints 1 when any bit of a number equals 0: %d\n", //PRINT GOES HERE);
```

Comment: @ScottHunter I have currently tried things like "!b", "!!(b ^ 0xF)", "!(!b)", and have unfortunately not had success in getting the result that I need

Comment: Does your task specifically tell you that it must be a 1 that is outputted? Or does it just have to be nonzero?

Comment: Does your task specifically tell you that the input is of type `int` and not `unsigned int`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The input is of type int and it says that a 1 must be outputted

Comment: Note that `!` and `!!` are (in)equality tests. I suspect that you are being asked to merge bits arithmetically by shifting and with bitwise operators and display the result.

Comment: If the input were `unsigned`, then my answer would be `!(b-0xFFFFFFFF)` (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`). However, this would not work with `signed` and, as has already been stated, using `!` could be considered an inequality test.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it is trivial and you do not have to guess how large `int` is. `b != -1` is enough and universal fot two complement numbers

Comment: @P__J__: As I have already pointed out as a comment to your answer, the question specifically mentions that inequality tests are prohibited.

Comment: If `!` is not considered a prohibited equality test, then the answer probably is `!!(b+1)`. However, I'm not sure if the question permits `+` either.

Comment: `!((unsigned)a ^ (unsigned)-1)`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel but I think the task is a bit more complicated. for example for 15 it shoul be zero and it should count from the first significant bit

Comment: Do you know the trick to test if a number is a power of 2? Have you tried adapting it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question but for two complement signed integer all bits are set for number `-1`

So you need to check if number is not equal `-1`

```
void foo(int a)
{
       printf("prints 1 when any bit of a number equals 0: %d\n", !((unsigned)a ^ (unsigned)-1));
}

int  main(void)
{
    foo(15);
}
```

But IMO it is too trivial. You probably want check starting from the first (most significant)set bit (so the `15` prints `0` but `14` prints `1`):

```
unsigned mask(int a)
{
    int bit;
    if(!((unsigned)a ^ (unsigned)-1)) return -1;
    for(bit = sizeof(a)*CHAR_BIT - 1; bit; bit--)
    {
        if(((unsigned)a & (1U << bit))) break;
    }
    return (1U << (bit + 1)) - 1;
}

void foo(int a)
{
       printf("prints 1 when any bit of a number equals 0: %d\n", !!((a & mask(a)) ^ mask(a)));
}


int  main(void)
{
    foo(15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create a mask with all 1's (~0x0) then XOR it with the number. If there are any 1's afterwords then at least one of the original bits was 0, and thus you can use &&1 to return 1 if there is at least one 1 and 0 if not.